# Hive Query not working

Tags: hive, hiveql

I am trying to get the HiveQL equivalent of a MySQL query.

In MySQL, I got a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE votes(
 user_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
 list_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
 node_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
 direction ENUM('UP', 'DOWN') NOT NULL, 
 PRIMARY KEY (user_id, list_id, node_id)
) ENGINE=innodb;
```

I have created a similar table in Hive using:

```
CREATE TABLE votes (
 user_id INT,
 list_id INT,
 node_id INT,
 direction STRING
) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED  
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

I copied 6 rows from MySQL table into the Hive table. So in Hive, I got:

```
hive> SELECT * FROM votes;
OK
28      390     400058  "UP"
28      390     400059  "DOWN"
90113   390     400058  "DOWN"
90113   390     400059  "UP"
323694  390     400058  "UP"
323694  390     400059  "UP"
Time taken: 0.059 seconds, Fetched: 6 row(s)
```

The following statement works fine in MySQL:

```
SELECT v1.list_id, v1.node_id, v2.list_id, v2.node_id, 
SUM(IF(v1.direction="UP" AND v2.direction="UP", 1, 0)) AS uu, 
SUM(IF(v1.direction="UP" AND v2.direction="DOWN", 1, 0)) AS ud, 
SUM(IF(v1.direction="DOWN" AND v2.direction="UP", 1, 0)) AS du, 
SUM(IF(v1.direction="DOWN" AND v2.direction="DOWN", 1, 0)) AS dd
FROM votes v1
JOIN votes v2 ON v1.user_id=v2.user_id
GROUP BY v1.list_id, v1.node_id, v2.list_id, v2.node_id;
```

which outputs:

```
390 400058  390 400058  2   0   0   1
390 400058  390 400059  1   1   1   0
390 400059  390 400058  1   1   1   0
390 400059  390 400059  2   0   0   1
```

However the same statement is not giving the correct counts in Hive:

```
hive> SELECT v1.list_id AS lid, v1.node_id AS nid, v2.list_id AS rlid, v2.node_id AS rnid,
    > SUM(IF(v1.direction="UP" AND v2.direction="UP", 1, 0)) AS uu,
    > SUM(IF(v1.direction="UP" AND v2.direction="DOWN", 1, 0)) AS ud,
    > SUM(IF(v1.direction="DOWN" AND v2.direction="UP", 1, 0)) AS du,
    > SUM(IF(v1.direction="DOWN" AND v2.direction="DOWN", 1, 0)) AS dd
    > FROM votes v1
    > JOIN votes v2 ON v1.user_id=v2.user_id
    > GROUP BY v1.list_id, v1.node_id, v2.list_id, v2.node_id;

...

Status: Finished successfully
OK
390     400058  390     400058  0       0       0       0
390     400058  390     400059  0       0       0       0
390     400059  390     400058  0       0       0       0
390     400059  390     400059  0       0       0       0
Time taken: 19.127 seconds, Fetched: 4 row(s)
```

How do I fix this?

Also, I found a post where someone mentioned it is best to avoid self join in Hive. If this is true, can you explain why and a better query to achieve what I am trying to get?

Comment: I have added answer to this with Hive serdes. Pls add your feedback to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like those quotation marks are actually part of the UP/DOWN value strings, so you need to include them in the comparison statements.  I was able to get your expected results using this Hive query:

```
SELECT v1.list_id, v1.node_id, v2.list_id, v2.node_id,
  SUM(IF(v1.direction='"UP"' AND v2.direction='"UP"', 1, 0)) AS uu,
  SUM(IF(v1.direction='"UP"' AND v2.direction='"DOWN"', 1, 0)) AS ud,
  SUM(IF(v1.direction='"DOWN"' AND v2.direction='"UP"', 1, 0)) AS du,
  SUM(IF(v1.direction='"DOWN"' AND v2.direction='"DOWN"', 1, 0)) AS dd
FROM votes v1
JOIN votes v2 ON v1.user_id=v2.user_id
GROUP BY v1.list_id, v1.node_id, v2.list_id, v2.node_id;
```

Note that the UP/DOWN values are now surrounded with single quotes to make sure the double quotes are interpreted as part of the value.

Comment: That's correct! I had quotes in the CSV dump, so the quotes also became part of the value. Thx

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to [**use Hive `CSVSerde`**](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/CSV+Serde) when creating table. So that **double quotes will be handled automatically** in SELECT query, as `DEFAULT_QUOTE_CHARACTER` is `"` in CSVSerde.

```
CREATE TABLE votes (user_id INT, list_id INT, node_id INT, direction STRING) 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde' 
     WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("separatorChar" = "\t") -- default seperator is ,
STORED AS CSVFILE;
```

Running the SELECT Query

```
SELECT v1.list_id AS lid, v1.node_id AS nid, 
     v2.list_id AS rlid, v2.node_id AS rnid,
     SUM(IF(v1.direction="UP" AND v2.direction="UP", 1, 0)) AS uu,
     SUM(IF(v1.direction="UP" AND v2.direction="DOWN", 1, 0)) AS ud,
     SUM(IF(v1.direction="DOWN" AND v2.direction="UP", 1, 0)) AS du,
     SUM(IF(v1.direction="DOWN" AND v2.direction="DOWN", 1, 0)) AS dd
     FROM votes v1
     JOIN votes v2 ON v1.user_id=v2.user_id
     GROUP BY v1.list_id, v1.node_id, v2.list_id, v2.node_id;


+------+---------+-------+---------+-----+-----+-----+-----+--+
| lid  |   nid   | rlid  |  rnid   | uu  | ud  | du  | dd  |
+------+---------+-------+---------+-----+-----+-----+-----+--+
| 390  | 400058  | 390   | 400058  | 2   | 0   | 0   | 1   |
| 390  | 400058  | 390   | 400059  | 1   | 1   | 1   | 0   |
| 390  | 400059  | 390   | 400058  | 1   | 1   | 1   | 0   |
| 390  | 400059  | 390   | 400059  | 2   | 0   | 0   | 1   |
+------+---------+-------+---------+-----+-----+-----+-----+--+
```